# Proving a spanning set is a closed subspace of a Hilbert Space

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces

Suppose that $\mathbb R^2$ is a Hilbert space. I am having trouble with proving that $span\{(cosx,sinx)\}$ is closed, where x $\in$ $[0,2]$.

This small proof comes from a big proof, which is essential to finish off.

Comment: I believe it is 'closed in the topological sense' for the following reason: We know that Hilbert space is a complete inner product space. Moreover, since it is $\mathbb R^2$, the norm comes from inner product space. Hence, we can use topology as in a normed space, which involves closed ball, open ball, open/close subsets of a normed space and so on. This is how I figured out it should be 'closed in topological sense'. I am not sure about 'closed in algebraic sense': like open intervals and closed intervals?

Comment: Finite dimensional subspaces are always closed...

Comment: Is $span{(cosx,sinx)}$ a finite-dimensional subspace? May I see the proof of "$span{(cosx,sinx)}$" if handy? Thanks

Comment: a span is always a subspace and $\mathbb R^2$ is already finite dimensional...

Comment: $\mathbb R^2$ is finite-dimensional, but how can we be sure that $span(cosx,sinx)$ is finite-dimensional?

Comment: $\mathbb R^2$ is the only space you have mentioned. If you are not asking about subspaces of $\mathbb R^2$, you should rephrase your question.